# ActiveModelSerializer How to configure `key_transform` and `adapter` differently for different API versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, json-api

I have 2 API versions(`v1` and `v2`) under different namespaces and I wish to use `adapter: :json_api` and `key_transform: :camel_lower` for V2 and keep the legacy untouched(in terms of response type).
Is there a way to achieve it ?
Like, having a base serializer to configure changes in and inherit all V2 serializers from it ?